# How to load and edit all strings from php file using html form

Tags: php, string, localization, backend

I need to load all the strings from a php file into html input forms and then be able to edit them.

Im working on a small web app and recently we decided to add 2nd language. Currently most strings used on the app are contained in 2 php files. As long as it is only me (developer) adjusting the texts, using code editing program is fine. However, with the addition of 2nd language I need someone else to add and adjust translations. And it should be done in the administration of the application.
I believe it should not be that hard to achieve, however I cant come up with an idea how to load and then save those strings.

Example of php file:

```
<?
$welcomeMessage = "Hello, this is welcome message";
$goodbyeMessage = "It was nice seeing you. Goodbye!";
?>
```

How I plan to do the HTML:

```
<label>$STRINGNAME</label><input value="$STRINGVALUE"><input submit  value="save">
```

I am not sure if this approach is any good so I will be also glad if you point me to another direction.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to store those strings outside of php. Then they can be loaded in whatever language you need. Store them in database, or in external file (eg. in json format).

Comment: You are most probably right with the database approach. I had some more time to think it through and I would need to change the strings to an array. Meaning I would have one big array containing all the strings. Then I would use for function to cycle through all of the strings to output them to html input. So far so good. But I could not figure out how would I save changes. I would have to delete the whole content from the file and somehow insert all the values back (with changes). It does not seem very efficient.

Comment: Also note that problem with this approach is when multiple simultaneous requests are trying to change values in this array and they are overwriting file, some changes may easily be lost.